Prove that the feasible set is non-empty.
Consider the following optimization problem:
$$
\begin{alignat}{3}
 & \underset{{\bf x}}{minimize} \quad & f({\bf x}) &= x_{0,0} & &  \\
 & subject~to \quad & h({\bf x}) &= \sum_{d=1}^{D} \sum_{h=1}^{H_d} x_{d,h} - n = 0 & & \\
  &  & g_d({\bf x}) &= \sum_{h=1}^{H_d} A^2_{d,h} \left(\tfrac{1}{x_{d,h}} -\tfrac{1}{N_{d,h}}\right) - x_{0,0} = 0, & d&=1,\ldots,D, \\    
  &  & g_{d,h}({\bf x}) &= x_{d,h} - N_{d,h} \le 0, & \qquad d&=1,\ldots,D,~ h=1,\ldots,H_d ,& &
\end{alignat}
$$
where
${\bf x} = (x_{0,0}, x_{1,1},x_{1,2},\ldots,x_{D,~H_D}) > {\bf 0}$ is the optimization variable, and
$D,~
H_1,\ldots,H_D,~
A_{1,1},A_{1,2},\ldots,A_{D,H_D},~
N_{1,1},N_{1,2},\ldots,N_{D,H_D},~
n < \sum_{d=1}^{D} \sum_{h=1}^{H_d} N_{d,h},$
are given strictly positive numbers.
I would like to prove that the feasible set is non-empty. Any comment is welcome. Thank you!
